# Calling finish() in onPause in child activity so that user refocuses into parent activity. Child activity gets recreated instead

Tags: android, android-activity

I create a child activity "B" from activity "A". if the user should leave the app for any reason (most likely hitting the home button), I would like activity "B" to end and the app to be at activity "A" once the user resumes.

If I call `finish()` manually, activity B ends and it returns to activity A. This is the behaviour I would like to happen when the user leaves the app.

I have tried to call `finish()` in the `onPause()`, `onStop()` and in the `onUserLeavingHint()` of activity B. In each case, this appears to work correctly, and I can see `mParent.finishFromChild(this);` being called inside activity B.

However, as soon as the user switches back to the app, the `onCreate()` of activity B gets called and the user ends up in activity B.

How can I ensure I end up in the parent activity when I call `finish()` from within an `onStop()` (or similar) handler?

**UPDATE:** It appears that the issue is related to activity B being declared as using a SingleInstance launch mode. Removing this feature seems to have resolved the issue. Changing this has introduced other issues that I have since managed to fix.

Comment: Are you calling `.finish()` before or after the `super.onPause()`?

Comment: When you mean parent/child, are you using `ActivityGroup`?

Comment: I have tried putting the finish both before and after the superclass call, the behaviour appears to be identical. I am not using ActivityGroup. I am just creating a new intent for activity B from Activity A, which works fine when I finish() manually. Just not when I call finish inside onPause(), etc. A point worth noting: activity B is set as SingleInstance launch in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this happening is that Activity B is set as a SingleInstance Launch Mode. The reason it was set to this (by another developer) is somewhat related to the reason I had wished the activity was ended when the app is in the background - it was to ensure the user could not reach this activity by hitting back on any other activities subsequently dispatched from Activity B.

To resolve this. I first ensured no activities could be created from B. To instead return from B and pass any required Intents on to A. Simplifying the back stack. (Calling activity B with `startActivityForResult()` is one possible way of doing this.)

Now, the reason SingleInstance causes this issue to arise in this scenario, is because Activity B is launched in a seperate new task. When the user attempts to resume, they re-enter this single-activity task. The rest of the app is running in a seperate task. The only thing the task can reasonably be expected to do is relaunch the activity. When the user presses back, the only thing it can do from there is to close the task (and hence appear to exit the app). For the expected behaviour to occur the user would have had to have selected the other, first task (through a long click of the task list).

Hopefully this self-answer can help someone who has encountered a similar issue.